# Floating DIV column out of position

Tags: css, html, css-float

I can't find the reason why the third column [at my site](http://www.umestentorg.ru/) slid down.  You can see third column under the center column. Something has changed and it slid down.  Can you find what may have happened?

Comment: You may wish to start with validation. You have a mad mixture of HTML5 and XHTML in there

Answer (score 2):

It looks like in this div, the bottom padding seems a bit excessive:

```
<div id="articlesBlock" class="rightCol" style="margin-top: 3px; 
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; padding-bottom: 2214px;">
```

Comment: @nice spot on what was probably a typo